# Command Prompt input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Windows 7 laptop, and I think I installed everything correctly, and I am trying to follow a couple tutorials to learn from. I can make a new application ok, and I can start the server just fine by typing "rails server", and I can go to the localhost:3000 'welcome aboard' page just fine, but after that the tutorials ask me to type other stuff into the command prompt window. The problem is, with the server running, I can't type anything into the command prompt window! I'm obviously doing something wrong.. anyone have any idea of what I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to open another command window.

I set up students to use more than one command window like this:

- one for typing most commands
- one for running the server
- one for printing the log file using the "tail -f" command to show ongoing progress
- one for running rails console

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I think I just figured out that I was supposed to stop the server before going onto the next steps in the tutorials..but they didn't tell me to. Ah well It's getting a little late, think I will call it a day!

Comment: Please ignore my last comment! Now that I'm at it again, I see that I am supposed to have the server running. Multiple command windows is working fine though. Ugh, my brain doesn't work at 3 in the morning.